# Error: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, emulation

I am trying to run the emulator (which has worked fine in the past), but I am getting an error, the full console output is here:

```
Eamons-MBP:myapp eamonwhite$ ionic cordova emulate ios --target="iPhone-6, 10.3"
Running app-scripts build: --address 0.0.0.0 --port 8100 --p 8100 --livereload-port 35729 --r 35729 --iscordovaserve --externalIpRequired --nobrowser

[15:22:46]  build dev started ... 
[15:22:46]  clean started ... 
[15:22:46]  clean finished in 2 ms 
[15:22:46]  copy started ... 
[15:22:46]  transpile started ... 
[15:22:50]  transpile finished in 3.99 s 
[15:22:50]  preprocess started ... 
[15:22:50]  deeplinks started ... 
[15:22:50]  deeplinks finished in 209 ms 
[15:22:50]  preprocess finished in 210 ms 
[15:22:50]  webpack started ... 
[15:22:57]  copy finished in 11.27 s 
[15:23:06]  webpack finished in 15.69 s 
[15:23:06]  sass started ... 
[15:23:07]  sass finished in 1.36 s 
[15:23:07]  postprocess started ... 
[15:23:07]  postprocess finished in 6 ms 
[15:23:07]  lint started ... 
[15:23:07]  build dev finished in 21.31 s 
> cordova emulate ios --target "iPhone-6, 10.3"
Running command: /Users/eamonwhite/ionicmane/myapp/hooks/after_prepare/ionic-minify.js /Users/eamonwhite/ionicmane/myapp

Error: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined


[ERROR] Cordova encountered an error.
        You may get more insight by running the Cordova command above directly.

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova emulate ios --target "iPhone-6, 10.3" (exit code 1).
```

I am not sure what the error is referring to, everything worked fine days ago.

Comment: Give this a shot: `cd platforms/ios/cordova/node_modules/` and then `sudo npm install ios-sim@latest`. Then try again.

Comment: i get this error `Error: tsconfig: Cannot read file '/Users/eamonwhite/ionicmane/myApp/platforms/ios/cordova/node_modules/tsconfig.json': ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/eamonwhite/ionicmane/myApp/platforms/ios/cordova/node_modules/tsconfig.json'.` I have verified that tsconfig.json isnt there.

Comment: I tried to `npm install ios-sim@latest` in the root directory and then i did `ionic package build ios` and tried again and I got the same `Error: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

Comment: the tsconfig error was because i wasnt in the root directory...but still no luck

Comment: I looked at the xcode project and when i run ios emulate it generates a missing files error `file:///Users/eamonwhite/ionicmane/myApp/node_modules/@types/node/package.json: warning: Missing file: /Users/eamonwhite/ionicmane/myApp/node_modules/@types/node/package.json is missing from working copy` it also cant find `index.d.ts` and a `README` and `LICENSE` in the same directory

Comment: @ewizard I'm having similar issue and executing npm blabla ios-sim@latest changes nothing.
As a temporary solution try to use: ionic cordova emulate ios --target=iPhone-6
It is working as a temporary solution for me. Does it work for you?

Comment: Did you try removing the and readding the platform?

Comment: @David no ill give that a shot

Comment: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/2487